# Spotify api add track to playlist

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, spotify

I am using ReactJS and trying to make simple site using the [Spotify api](https://developer.spotify.com/console/). 
I am also using the js package [spotify-web-api-js](https://github.com/JMPerez/spotify-web-api-js). I have succeeded to get the current song playing and able to show it in the browser.

```
  getNowPlaying(){
spotifyApi.getMyCurrentPlaybackState()
  .then((response) => {
    this.setState({
      nowPlaying: {
          name: response.item.name,
          albumArt: response.item.album.images[0].url
        }
    });
  })
}

 //this is from the github link above

  Constr.prototype.getMyCurrentPlaybackState = function(options, callback) {
    var requestData = {
      url: _baseUri + '/me/player'
    };
    return _checkParamsAndPerformRequest(requestData, options, callback);
  };
```

But the problem I am facing is to add a track to my playlist. I have tried to use the function `replaceTracksInPlaylist` from [spotify-web-api-js](https://github.com/JMPerez/spotify-web-api-js) but I cant manage to get it to work, I always get the 403 Forbidden error.

```
  addToPlayList(){
    spotifyApi.addTracksToPlaylist(listID, listOfSongID, callback);
  }

  //this is from the github link above 
  Constr.prototype.replaceTracksInPlaylist = function(playlistId, uris, callback) {
    var requestData = {
      url: _baseUri + '/playlists/' + playlistId + '/tracks',
      type: 'PUT',
      postData: { uris: uris }
    };
    return _checkParamsAndPerformRequest(requestData, {}, callback);
  };
```

The first example also requires authentication as a access token but why does it not work when adding to a playlist?

I have also changed the [scopes](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/general/guides/scopes/) to the correct ones that the api documentation says i should use, `playlist-modify-public` and `playlist-modify-private`

```
var scope = 'playlist-modify-public playlist-modify-private user-read-private user-read-email user-read-playback-state';
```

I can test the api call from the [api documentation site](https://developer.spotify.com/console/post-playlist-tracks/) and insert  my oauth token, track and the playlist id there, and that works fine, I also get this back from the call. I cant think of anything else to try and need some help figuring out the next step.

[image]